# VSCode stopping C++ .exe execution after trying to display a special character

Tags: c++

I was trying to print a special character, like à or è, in VSCode with C++. After compiling the code (g++ gave me no errors) and executing it, when the console had to print one of those characters the execution stopped suddently.

I tried using \xa8, \xa3 and char(133), char(212) but none of them worked. Did anyone got this issue yet?
I also tried to launch the .exe generated by the compiler in cmd (outside of VSCode) and it worked perfectly, so in teory it's VSCode's fault.

Example code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Special characher: "<<char(133);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just because something compiles without errors does *not* mean that it is correct.

Comment: I tested this on windows 10. In powershell (which is the VSCode default shell in windows) it outputs: `Special characher:`. In cmd.exe it outputs: `Special characher: à`

Comment: You have to know which encoding you are using on both sides.